# Webscraping data from Familysearch.org using R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape the table of Brazilian records at familySearch.org (see URL bellow) using R, more especifically the rvest package.

Fist selected the table on the website with "selctor gadget". Depending on how I click the selctor returns: "#hr-data-table" or "td". None of them seems to work:

```
library(rvest)
url <- 'https://familysearch.org/search/record/results?count=75&englishSubcountryName=Brasil&query=%2Brecord_country%3ABrazil%20%2Brecord_subcountry%3A'
url %>% html() %>%  html_node("#hr-data-table") %>% html_text()

Error in xml_apply(x, XML::xmlValue, ..., .type = character(1)) : 
  Unknown input of class: NULL

url %>% html() %>%  html_node("td") %>% html_text()

[1] ""

#replacing html_text() with html_table() also does not work.
```

Any ideas on how to make this work, preferably within R?

Answer (score 2):

**Making this a non-answer answer to illustrate it more than a comment wld allow.**

---

The site uses XHR requests to dynamically populate the tables. You'll need to either use selenium (RSelenium) or bring up developer tools and look at the requests that are being made (reload the site after bringing up dev tools or firebug or whatever your browser has).

Here's the "Copy as cURL" version of the XHR request for the tabular data:

```
curl 'https://familysearch.org/search/records?count=75&query=%2Brecord_country%3ABrazil' 
  -H 'Cookie: fs_experiments=u%3D-anon-%2Ca%3Dshared-ui%2Cs%3D4ad72a2f25d45cd9ae7c92e412c176e5%2Cv%3D010011001101000000011111111100111010110100001010000110011000110001011000000010011000000%2Cb%3D82%26a%3Dhome%2Cs%3D32f8f352ce4eaac984ab4a66aca8f354%2Cv%3D1101100110000110000000000100110011101%2Cb%3D19%26a%3Dcampaign%2Cs%3D296f4e3066991d8e9584fd6eb21e8c7c%2Cv%3D0101011111110010110001111%2Cb%3D34%26a%3Dsearch%2Cs%3D7acb79194da98cdfc4a29ecf17854668%2Cv%3D1111111110011110111111111111111101000000000000000000%2Cb%3D83; fs_search_history=https%3A//familysearch.org/search/record/results%3Fcount%3D75%26englishSubcountryName%3DBrasil%26query%3D%252Brecord_country%253ABrazil%2520%252Brecord_subcountry%253A' 
  -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch'
  -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8' 
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36' 
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 
  -H 'Accept: */*' 
  -H 'Referer: https://familysearch.org/search/record/results?count=75&englishSubcountryName=Brasil&query=%2Brecord_country%3ABrazil%20%2Brecord_subcountry%3A' 
  -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' 
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' 
  --compressed
```

Some or all of those may be required. You'll have to test it out tho.

It's pretty clear they have an API powering the site so you may want to consider writing them to see if you can get a copy of the unofficial/private API and just work with it that way vs scrape (scraping generally puts far more load on a server than an API call would).

You can either do that triage for the private API call requirements or use RSelenium to "click and scrape" the rendered DOM elements.